# "list indices must be integers or slices, not str" error while trying to post multiple instances of a model class using cURL in APIview django

Tags: rest, curl, postman

When trying to post multiple record using cURL but getting error:

> "list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

Models

```
class Books(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Authors(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Books, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="book")


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Serializers

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    book = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Books

        fields = '__all__'

class AuthorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Authors
        fields = '__all__'
```

Views for AuthorApiView class and post function

```
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Create a serializer instance with the request data
        

        serializer = AuthorSerializer(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            res = {"msg": "Author Created"}
            json_data = JSONRenderer().render(res)
            return HttpResponse(json_data, content_type="application/json")
        else:
            # Return a response with serilizer error
            return Response({"error":serializer.errors})
```

I want to post multiple record at once using cURL

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '[
  {"name": "Jack Rachel", "book": 2},
  {"name": "Jack Rachel", "book": 3},
  {"name": "Jack Rachel", "book": 10}
]' http://127.0.0.1:8000/authors/
```

I am getting error:

> "list indices must be integers or slices, not str".

Any help would be appreciated.